# OData on .Net Core doesn't return the right results on $select

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've added OData to my WebAPI project.

Versions:

1. Core 3.1
2. OData 7.3.0 (beta version in order to work with Core 3.x)
3. EF Core 3.1.0

Here is my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<Models.Contexts.EntityContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString:MailBackup"]));
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        services.AddOData();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
            routeBuilder.Expand().Select().OrderBy().Filter();
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();

    }
}
```

And the controller is:

```
[EnableQuery()]
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAll")]
public IQueryable<Models.EmailMessage> GetAll()
{    
    return this._context.EmailMessages;
}
```

The APIs are working fine, but when I try to add some OData action like $select I get the following and not the expected results:

```
{
    "instance": null,
    "container": {},
    "modelID": "529e8054-04c4-4729-aa91-d7eaf67a55d0",
    "untypedInstance": null,
    "instanceType": null,
    "useInstanceForProperties": false
},
{
    "instance": null,
    "container": {},
    "modelID": "529e8054-04c4-4729-aa91-d7eaf67a55d0",
    "untypedInstance": null,
    "instanceType": null,
    "useInstanceForProperties": false
},
```

Comment: I expect to have the list of EmailMessages with only the field specified in the $select parameter

Comment: @Jawad [Queryable] doesn't exist in .net core 3

Comment: @Jawad thanks, but it doesn't work. BTW parenthesis can be used to specify optional parameters of the query.

Comment: Does this work, ```[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]```

Comment: Can you share how OData model is configured?

Comment: same error result is happening with me. tried all possible ways but still no luck. any resolution till now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem. This solved the problem for me. Perhaps odata is not fully compatible with the new JSON serializer in Asp.Net 3.1. I don't know.

```cs
services.AddControllers(mvcOptions =>
           mvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
       .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: This is the answer!  Specifically, the issue is that the System.Text.Json serializer is limited to iterations 32 levels deep.  Currently, there's no easy way to change the JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth value but is in the roadmap for dotnetcore 5: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094#issuecomment-567232806

Comment: You can find the NuGet at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/

Comment: Thank you, I was having the same issue and this help me to solve the problem. It seems that the problem is with net core 3.1 serializer :)

Answer (score 3):

> The APIs are working fine, but when I try to add some OData action like $select I get the following and not the expected results

I can reproduce the same issue in my `.NET Core 3.x` application with similar code as you shared, it seems that currently injecting OData services into existing API controller with the following code snippet does not support well for .NET Core 3.x.

```
routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
```

And based on my test, it can work well in `.NET Core 2.x`. To make `$select` functionality work fine in `.NET Core 3.x`, currently, we can try this workaround:

*In Startup.cs*

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(app.ApplicationServices);

builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");


app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
    // and this line to enable OData query option, for example $filter

    routeBuilder.Expand().Select().OrderBy().Filter();

    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "api", builder.GetEdmModel());

});
```

*In ODataController*

```
public class ProductsController : ODataController
{
    // ...
    //code logic here
    // ...

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Product> Get()
    {
        var products = _context.Products;

        return products;
    }

    // ...

}
```

*Test Result*

[image]

For more information, please check:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/netcore#e-configure-the-odata-endpoint

Comment: [Similar issue](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1748#issuecomment-565022034) has been reported on github, we can trace updates about OData supported for ASP.NET Core 3.x

Comment: that issue is different. to get rid of that issue . i upgraded to 3.1 core and included <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="7.3.0-beta" />  package. now odata is partially working ..for me $filter,$groupby, $top is working fine. but like $ select ,$expand gives error  {
    "instance": null,
    "container": {},
    "modelID": "529e8054-04c4-4729-aa91-d7eaf67a55d0",
    "untypedInstance": null,
    "instanceType": null,
    "useInstanceForProperties": false
},

Comment: Hey guys, finally got it working.  as ODATA is not friendly with mvc api routes. just changed to odata routes working as expected.removed

Comment: Hey guys, finally got it working.  as ODATA is not friendly with mvc api routes. just changed to odata routes working as expected.removed routes.EnableDependencyInjection(); from routes delegate. intially my url was https://localhost:44352/api/controllername, now it is https://localhost:44352/odata/controllername. hope it makes sense for you. any query please let me know. under mvc route delegate keep only given two lines     routes.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Select().Expand();                           
               routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel(app));