# ASP.NET Core 5.0 OData $select not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

In my ASP.NET Core 5.0 REST API I am using
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v.7.5.2 and
Entity Framework v.5.0.2

I have a Controller that implements ODataController and a SearchContacts function.

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 50)]
[Route("[action]")]
public ActionResult<IQueryable<ContactModel>> SearchContacts()
{
    return this.Ok(this._context.Contacts.AsQueryable());
}
```

For SearchContacts I can use $filter, $top and $skip just fine.
When I try to use $select I get a strange result:

```
[
{
    "instance": null,
    "container": {},
    "modelID": "f4ca8855-11fa-4822-8f11-dc39b3c3c3f8",
    "untypedInstance": null,
    "instanceType": null,
    "useInstanceForProperties": false
},
{
    "instance": null,
    "container": {},
    "modelID": "f4ca8855-11fa-4822-8f11-dc39b3c3c3f8",
    "untypedInstance": null,
    "instanceType": null,
    "useInstanceForProperties": false
}
]
```

I tried updating Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData to version 7.5.4 but then I get an error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

> Error  CS1705  Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData, Version=7.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'Microsoft.OData.Edm, Version=7.7.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Edm' with identity 'Microsoft.OData.Edm, Version=7.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Comment: I had the unfortunate idea to use OData with .NET 5 as well. And Blazor WASM. Let's say that OData isn't exactly a priority for Microsoft. Have you considered GraphQL with eg HotChocolate? It's probably going to be easier than getting OData to work, and your API will be usable by a lot more clients

Comment: As for this problem, .NET 5 support was added in the 8.0 Preview versions. I encountered version conflicts as well. That's why I eventually switched to the 8 previews. I haven't encountered the problem you show though. What you post looks like metadata. What does your model, metadata and controllers look like?

Comment: BTW there's no need to wrap an `IQueryable` result in an `ActionResult`, you can return it directly

Comment: Looks like there's a duplicate after all [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381408/odata-on-net-core-doesnt-return-the-right-results-on-select). I didn't encounter this problem though, nor did I have to switch to JSON.NET at any pointt

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is the correct answer

Comment: @JamesD I doubt this would still work. Routing changed again in 8 RC

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it works, just had this specific issue and tested it on dotnet SDK 5.0.201

Comment: @JamesD that's not the only incompatibility, which is why I used 8 Preview in the first place. Only to find other problems. Both options are a compromise until 8 is released.