# OData response gets truncated when using query features

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

OData response gets truncated when using query features.

*Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData version 8.0.4*

**Without query parameters:**

[image]

**With select query parameter:**

[image]

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddNewtonsoftJson()
        .AddOData(opt => opt.EnableQueryFeatures().AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()));

    ...
}



 private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        var entitySetConfiguration = builder.EntitySet<GenericDocument>("Documents");
        entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.HasKey(entity => entity.IdStr);

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

**DocumentsController**

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok(_service.GetAll());
}
```

**Model**

```
[BsonCollection("my_documents")]
public class GenericDocument : Document
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string SupplierAddress { get; set; }
    public string SupplierIban { get; set; }
    public string BuyerName { get; set; }
    public string BuyerAddress { get; set; }
    public string BuyerIban { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public float Quantity { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public float TotalValueWithoutVat { get; set; }
    public float Vat { get; set; }
    public float Total { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Document : IDocument
{
    public string IdStr => Id.ToString();
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt => Id.CreationTime;
}
```

**What is _service and how does the GetAll() implementation in it looks like?**

```
private readonly IMongoRepository<GenericDocument> _repository;
public IQueryable<GenericDocument> GetAll()
{
     return  _repository.AsQueryable();
}
```

What could be the problem?

Some of the links, that I've checked:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/routing-in-asp-net-core-8-0-preview/

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1771?focusedCommentId=4145551&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-4145551

https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2021/07/intro-on-odata-v8-in-dotnet5-api.html

Comment: What is `_service` and how does the `GetAll()` implementation in it looks like?

Comment: @PhilP.  I've updated the question

Comment: Similar question asked before, [OData on .Net Core doesn't return the right results on $select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381408/odata-on-net-core-doesnt-return-the-right-results-on-select)

Comment: @kyo Tried it, same issue. Thanks